# Set parameter as int array for where in statement in dbal query builder throws array to string conversion exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, dbal

I try to bind parameter : [1, 2] in dbal querybuilder in WHERE IN statement

I tried to change `$qb->expr()->in()` to string version but nothing changed

QueryBuilder creation

```php
$qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.id AS id')
            ->from('category', 'c')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('c.id', ':categories'))->setParameter('categories', [1, 2], \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
```

Execution:

```php
$qb->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Error : `Array to string conversion`

Expects to bind array of integers to querybuilder statement

Comment: On which line you get this error and how the first part is connected to the second? where does $qb go? What is $this and $filter?

Comment: I just simplify code to show only problematic place. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

always love to quote documentation.

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->in('u.id', array(1, 2, 3))
// Make sure that you do NOT use something similar to $qb->expr()->in('value', array('stringvalue')) as this will cause Doctrine to throw an Exception.
// Instead, use $qb->expr()->in('value', array('?1')) and bind your parameter to ?1 (see section above)
public function in($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Func instance
```

source: [doctrine querybuilder docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html)

so essentially, unless the categories are numbers, you have to fill an array with placeholders and set those, or if they are numbers, you probably can just use the example.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have an entity which has a ManyToMany or ManyToOne with a Category entity,
You could just pass an array of Categories and it should work if the array is properly made like so :

```
qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.id AS id')
            ->from('category', 'c')
     ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('c.id',':categories'))->setParameter('categories', $categoriesArray);
```

Otherwise, you can try to use setParameter with your array of id by imploding the array :

```
qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.id AS id')
            ->from('category', 'c')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('c.id', ':categories'))->setParameter('categories', implode(",",[1, 2]));
```

Comment: the first one is what exactly the OP does and the second one obviously won't work as expected

Comment: The first one is not what the OP is doing, passing an Array of entities and an Array of integer is not the same thing.